# Hide the HTML video URL from the Control Center in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, asp.net

Is there a javascript or an HTML code to hide the video url in the iOS Control Center ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the control center is not accessible from JavaScript or HTML.

Comment: Is there a way to add an html parameter to show a title or something instead of url ?

Comment: No, there is no way to change that behavior. The only thing you can do is change the URL itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add title atribute, it'll display on control center instead of URL.